# Show performance/system logs on the Microsoft Mesh application

Tags: windows, performance, logging, microsoft-teams, hololens

I've been playing around with Microsoft Mesh (a remote AR/VR/MR collaboration solution for Teams) for a few days. The thing I want to know is if it’s possible to log some performance/system indicators when using the application. For example, frames per second, network I/O, CPU/Memory usage.

Since it runs on only HoloLens 2 (for now), whose OS is a modified version of Windows and CPU is ARM-based, it seems difficult to grab detailed information as in Linux where almost everything is open-sourced (I'm a newbie in Windows-related development).

I'm wondering if there are some APIs for these logs (whether system level or application level). Thank you all!

Answer (score 3):

You can use the **Performance Tracking** in the device portal, refer to [Using the Windows Device Portal - Mixed Reality | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/advanced-concepts/using-the-windows-device-portal#performance-tracing), you can refer to [Performance tracing and analysis with WPA - Mixed Reality | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/advanced-concepts/hololens-performance-tracing-howto) for further analysis of this data, and you can also get this data via [Device portal API reference - Mixed Reality | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/advanced-concepts/device-portal-api-reference#performance-data).

Comment: Thank you! If I understand correctly these tools do a great job at system-level profiling, which is a great help to me. I also want to know if there are some APIs for application-level user-perceived indicators like frames per second (FPS), freezes and lags, etc.

Comment: Glad you received the link to the tools.  These are useful for sure on monitoring system when application is running.   To help on API level, we do have following available to help developers of apps  (VisualProfiler):  https://github.com/microsoft/VisualProfiler-Unity.   More docs are here too:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/mrtk-unity/mrtk2/features/diagnostics/using-visual-profiler?view=mrtkunity-2022-05

Comment: @Nathan-MSFT The VisualProfiler is useful when developing apps. Is there a similar tool that can be used to diagnose an already released app, i.e., Microsoft Mesh?

Comment: @Nathan-MSFT And maybe you can help me out on a slightly different question... Are there any network-related tools (like ping or traceroute available in Windows CMD) in HoloLens 2 so that I can perform some network monitoring tasks? (I've read some outdated posts saying Windows Device Portal has some kind of `remote CMD` feature but it seems not available on HoloLens 2 now)

Comment: @Nathan-MSFT Sorry for the bother.  Just one step further, maybe some apps like npcap or Wireshark are available in HoloLens 2?

Comment: You can monitor the network with Fiddler and Wireshark on your PC. Please refer to [Diagnose HoloLens 2 network issues with Fiddler and Wireshark - Microsoft Tech Community](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-it-pro-blog/diagnose-hololens-2-network-issues-with-fiddler-and-wireshark/ba-p/2322458).

Comment: @ZuochengWang-MSFT As I posted in Microsoft Q&A, maybe something like a HoloLens 2 version of Wireshark is of great help

Comment: We can continue the discussion in the Microsoft Q&A.